# .NET component to view and annotate documents and images

Tags: asp.net, pdf, image, documents, annotate

I need a component that I can install on my server that can be used in an ASP.NET Web Application to:

1. Display word documents, PDF documents, images in the browser.
2. Allow these documents to be annotated online and have those annotation saved for redisplay later.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Jon, You may want to add Flash and/or Silverlight tag to your question.  That will attract the attention of developers experienced in these areas.

Answer (score 1):

Only a technology like Flash or Silverlight would be able to approach providing that functionality.  The biggest benefits would be avoid cross-browser/platform issues and  decent security.

Also, I would be guessing that if Flash/Silverlight components are available to do this, they would not be cheap due to the licensing of Adobe and Microsoft document formats etc.

Standard .NET custom/user controls are simply not an option as they generate HTML based user interfaces.

Sorry I don't have any more  specific suggestions.