# Annotation Control (or Document Control w/ Annotation Support) in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, annotations

I am looking for a .NET library (or, more specifically, a .NET component) which allows me to write annotations to a document (not specifically a Word document - the component itself could display a document which I can also add annotations to).  Even better would be something with similar functionality to the reviewing process in Microsoft Word, but I would be happy with just basic annotations.

I haven't been able to find anything very promising in Google searches, so I was wondering if SO would have any suggestions.

(Note: Unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557763/net-component-to-view-and-annotate-documents-and-images), my application is a standalone app and I am not looking to do this on the web.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you who might be looking, [ScintillaNET](http://www.codeplex.com/ScintillaNET) supports annotations as well as markers (which is what I was looking for).  The documentation is a little bit difficult to parse through (specifically the [Scintilla documentation](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html), which ScintillaNET comes from), but it is easy once you start getting the hang of it.

Hope this helps!